# Best way to "kill" an Intent - Android

Tags: android, android-intent, onresume, android-intentservice

I have a Broadcast Receiver to receive notifications via GCM that are then handle by an IntentService as explained in the docs of Android developers. My IntentService creates a notification, when the user clicks in this notification the MainActivity is launched and in onResume I get the extras of the Intent via:

```
Bundle mBucket = getIntent().getExtras();
```

I use them to create an AlertDialog, that has a link to a website. I would like to know how to handle this:

1. When the user clicks on the link, and then returns to the app, there are two AlertDialogs, since onResume is once again called (I guess). How can I avoid this?
2. If the activity is not visible but not killed, when the user clicks on the Notification, the Dialogbox is not shown.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: AlertDialogs are attached to the parent context, in this case your Activity. If it isn't visible, your AlertDialog won't be either as far as I know. You may want to create your own Activity and set it's theme to a Dialog. You can also use a boolean to make sure you only open the AlertDialog once.